# Auto-complete mode doesn't turn on automatically in ObjC buffers

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I load auto-complete mode like this:

```
(let ((ac-path "path/to/auto-complete"))
  (add-to-list 'load-path ac-path)
  (require 'auto-complete-config)
  (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories (concat ac-path "ac-dict"))
  (ac-config-default))
```

It works fine with C major mode, but doesn't turn on automatically when I open ObjC files. I can still turn it on manually and it will work fine along with the ObjC major mode.

Here's a snippet from the docs regarding ObjC major mode:

```
The hook `c-mode-common-hook' is run with no args
at mode initialization, then `objc-mode-hook'.
```

If I understand correctly, auto-complete adds a hook to the `c-mode-common-hook`, but `objc-mode-hook` somehow overrides it. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While looking through the source code of `auto-complete.el`, I've stumbled upon this definition

```
(defcustom ac-modes
  '(emacs-lisp-mode
    lisp-interaction-mode
    c-mode cc-mode c++-mode
    java-mode clojure-mode scala-mode
    scheme-mode
    ocaml-mode tuareg-mode
    perl-mode cperl-mode python-mode ruby-mode
    ecmascript-mode javascript-mode js-mode js2-mode php-mode css-mode
    makefile-mode sh-mode fortran-mode f90-mode ada-mode
    xml-mode sgml-mode)
  "Major modes `auto-complete-mode' can run on."
  :type '(repeat symbol)
  :group 'auto-complete)
```

It turns out that `auto-complete` doesn't have a true global mode. It is enabled only with those major modes that are included in the `ac-modes` variable.

So, adding the following line to the `.emacs` file has solved the issue for me.

```
; add this line after the auto-complete mode has been loaded
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'objc-mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
(defun my-objc-mode-hook ()
   (auto-complete-mode 1))
(add-hook 'objc-mode-hook 'my-objc-mode-hook)
```

Note 1: The function `auto-complete-mode` is a toggle function, when called with no arguments.

Note 2: It's possible to add an anonymous function using `lambda`, but this have several drawbacks. The most important ones are: modifying the function and reevaluating the expression will add the modified function **in addition** to the earlier version and `C-h v xxx` will print the full unformatted lambda function, which typically is hopeless to read and understand.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Is there a way to check if the hook itself is working, like a print statement to debug it? I'd really like to look at the sequence of actions Emacs performs when opening an ObjC file. That could help debug the problem. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could add a `(message "Running my-objc-mode-hook")` inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
(add-hook 'objc-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)
```

That should do it if you're using auto-complete-mode.  You can add more complex things to mode hooks by doing:

```
(add-hook 'objc-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                              (something-with arguments)))
```

Note that both arguments to add-hook are quoted, this is necessary and if you add unquoted functions they will probably not work.

Comment: Adding `(add-hook 'objc-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)` after the `(ac-config-default)` doesn't make it work. I wonder if it could be a conflict with some other mode/plugin?